# Maven and JavaFX project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm having troubles trying to configure Maven and JavaFX project in IntelliJ.

First I've had no idea how to do it, so I've found the following solution:

1. Create regular JavaFX project like you normally do in Intellij
2. Add Maven support to it by clicking following: Right click on project --> "Add Framework Support" and then check Maven

After first step application was working (ofcourse, because it's just normal JavaFX project), then after second step packages have changed, so I had to set package for every class; I've done that, and I've seen no errors. But when I try to run the app I get the following error, on picture:

And I've also moved sample.fxml to resources folder.

Maybe I need to set the groupId to something but I don't know what, I have tried setting it to name of the package (sample), but it didn't work.
[image]

The rest of the code:

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../../resources/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

public class Controller {
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full stack trace instead of the picture? Also you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: I appreciate the edit, but try not to use pictures for questions and copy and paste the code into the question instead.

Comment: yeah, but there is no much code, just the code that gets generated by the IDE when you create a project.

Comment: Just because theres not a lot doesnt mean its not important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way more easy for me.

1. Create folder under `resources` called `samples` (same in `src/main/java`)
2. Change the line:  `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../../resources/sample.fxml"));` for
   `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));`

Comment: you mean create package sample in resources? didnt help

Comment: I dont know what I just did but it works now, thanks! :) it works both with "/sample.fxml" and "sample.fxml" too, what is the difference? "sample.fxml" makes more sense to me

Comment: Yes. But If you don't want. Put samples.fxml under resources and change a line to: Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));

Comment: I prefer use /sample.fxml. Because it says the file is in the root.

Comment: well in my case this worked: Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../samples/sample.fxml"));

Answer (score 0):

I redid what you say you did, i.e. I made a JavaFX project and then added framework support.

After I added the Maven support, I moved the `sample.fxml` into the `resources` directory, since it is a resource.

I ended up having to change the `package sample;` to `package main.java.sample;` in both the `Main` and the `Controller` classes.

After this, I had to change the `sample.fxml` controller reference from `fx:controller="sample.Controller"` to `fx:controller="main.java.sample.Controller"`

After this, it ran successfully.

The core of your error is the `java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required`. When you added the Maven support, it moved your directories, so your `package sample;` is no longer correct, since the `sample` directory is no longer a direct child of your project. So, you must change where the `package` is pointing to, in this case your `sample` directory is located at `main.java.sample`. You must also not forget to edit the `sample.fxml` file as well, since it references your `Controller` class via the `fx:controller`.

Comment: Can you post code like I did, like you told me to do? My Controller and Main class are in sample package, and that causes no problem, but if I change it main.java.sample, I get error. I know it works with sample because it runs normally if I just put some System.out.println() code in main method. Have moved sample.fxml to resources, but didn't help. Still getting the same error like before (RuntimeException, not NullPointer)

Comment: @Scarass If you can't run it, then it is still a problem. Did you try to follow all of the instructions?

Comment: just one quick digression so we can continue talking: do you know how is Intelli Sense feature from Visual Studio generally called in other IDE's?

Comment: If you are looking for errors, you can press `F2` in the file and it will go to the next error.

Comment: i mean, if i rename packages of classes as you suggested I get "Intelli Sense" error, that's why I asked about Intelli Sense. I know the problem are not the packages, because if I run some just dummy code like System.out.println() from start(Stage), it works. And I get no "Intelli Sense" errors right now.

Comment: what is your groupId in pom.xml?

Comment: The only difference between your code and my code is I have `package main.java.sample;` and `fx:controller="main.java.sample.Controller"` Also, you should be running this by clicking on the play button next to your `Main` class contructor. As opposed to in Run.

Comment: can you make a picture of directory hierarchy and Main class like I did? thanks